# Adding padding to drop down select active item

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to drop down items that are active, however it doesn't seem to be possible. They want me to move

[image]
to this:

[image]

so that there is some extra padding on the left. However I canno't seem to target the active state.

html:

```
  <select class="input-select  gender-dropdown"     id="dwfrm_profile_customer_customergender"     name="dwfrm_profile_customer_customergender" style="-webkit-appearance: none;">
   <option class="select-option" label="Male" value="1">Male</option>
   <option class="select-option" label="Female" value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
```

- I found that removiing the -webkit-appearance: none makes it space properly but it also removes the bottom border

Comment: share your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `padding`, like this

```css
.input-select {
  padding: 6px 24px 6px 12px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<select class="input-select gender-dropdown" id="dwfrm_profile_customer_customergender" name="dwfrm_profile_customer_customergender" style="-webkit-appearance: none;">
  <option class="select-option" label="Male" value="1"> Male</option>
  <option class="select-option" label="Female" value="2"> Female</option>
</select>
```